# PDFView backgroundColor when using usePageViewController

Tags: ios11, uipageviewcontroller, pdfkit, pdfview

when I set the `usePageViewController` on my `PDFView` instance

```
pdfView?.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: nil)
```

I can no longer set the backgroundColor with

```
pdfView?.backgroundColor =.red
```

I have to(I assume) set it at the `pageViewController` level.

Question is how to access the pageViewController as it is not a property on the pdfView?

Also what options can be set in the `usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: ???)`. Be super handy of can set backgroundColor there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immediately after you call usePageViewController, the subviews of the PDF View will still be a UIScrollView.  However if you wait for it to switch to the page view controller, then you can set the background color of that view.

In my case, I was loading the document I am displaying in viewDidLoad, and I set the background color in viewDidAppear by accessing the subview of the pdf View, for example:

```
self.pdfView?.subviews[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

I would add appropriate checks to make sure that the view is there and that it is actually a page view controller view, just in case Apple's implementation changes in the future.

Regarding your other question about the options passed to usePageViewController - those don't appear to be documented yet.

Comment: This didn’t work for me. Do you know if this works with iOS 13?